# Probability of measuring the label of representation in quantum Fourier transformaton

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, quantum-computation

I am going through [Normal Subgroup Reconstruction and Quantum
Computation Using Group Representations](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/HRT.stoc00.pdf). In Definition 2, the authors start with the following function.

$$
f : G \to \mathbb{C}
$$

Then the Fourier transform of $f$ at the irrep $\rho$ is defined as the $d_\rho \times d_\rho$ matrix:

$$
\hat{f}(\rho) = \sqrt{\frac{d_\rho}{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} f (g) \rho(g)
$$

In the quantum computational settings, the authors identify the superposition $\sum_{g \in G} f_g |g\rangle$ ($|a\rangle$ is a quantum state which is the $a$-th computational basis vector), with the function $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(g) = f_g$.

In this notation, $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)|g\rangle$ is mapped under the Fourier transform to $\sum_{\rho \in \hat{G}, 1\le i,j \le d_\rho} \hat{f}(\rho)_{i,j} |\rho, i, j\rangle$.

$(\rho, i, j)$ is the label of the $(\rho, i, j)$-th computational basis vector $|\rho, i, j\rangle$. $\hat{f}(\rho)_{i,j}$ is a complex number and the $(i,j)$-th element of the matrix $\hat{f}(\rho)$. $\hat{G}$ is the collection of all irreps of $G$.

The the authors say as follows.

> When the first portion of this triple is measured, we observe $\rho
>  \in \hat{G}$ with probability
>
> $$ \sum_{1\le i,j\le d_\rho} |\hat{f}(\rho)_{i,j}|^2 =
>  ||\hat{f}(\rho)||^2\\
>  = tr ((\hat{f}(\rho))^* \hat{f}(\rho)) $$

Here, ($\rho, i, j$) is the triple the authors are referring to. Measuring $\rho$ means measuring the qubits which encode the label $\rho$.

**My question:**

Why is $\sum_{1\le i,j\le d_\rho} |\hat{f}(\rho)_{i,j}|^2 =
 ||\hat{f}(\rho)||^2$ true?

Comment: What does "$\rho
> \in \hat{G}$" mean?

Comment: @joriki, that was a typo. I have fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{1\le i,j\le d_\rho} |\hat{f}(\rho)_{i,j}|^2 =
 ||\hat{f}(\rho)||^2$ is just the definition of the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) of the matrix $\hat{f}(\rho)$.